# WhereUsed with Tridion Anguilla GUI Framework

Tags: cme, gui-extensions

How can I get a list of WhereUsed with the Tridion Anguilla Framework?  I am adding an extra tab in my Component Edit window and want to shw the Used iems in the tab.

Here is my code:

```
console.log('before where used');
var filter = new Tridion.ContentManager.ListFilter();
filter.columns = $const.ColumnFilter.DEFAULT;
filter.conditions.InclLocalCopies = true;                       
console.log(filter);        
var list = tridion.Web.UI.ContentManager.WhereUsed.GetListUsingItems(    
    "tcm:175-279165-16",     
    filter,   
    filter.columns, //Tridion.Constants.ColumnFilter.DEFAULT,
    new function() { 
        console.log(arguments); 
    },     
    new function() { 
        console.log(arguments); 
    }   
);    
console.log('after');
```

And the Firebug output:

```
before where used
item.a...-279165 (line 663)
ListFilter { prototypeMembers={...}, interfaces={...}, properties={...}, more...}
item.a...-279165 (line 668)
[]
item.a...-279165 (line 674)
[]
```

The arrays of the results are empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Robert,

You got it almost right...
The way you can get the "where used" list is as follows:

```java
//Get the item:
$item = $models.getItem("tcm:27-2899");

//Define a filter:
$filter = new Tridion.ContentManager.ListFilter();
$filter.columns = $const.ColumnFilter.DEFAULT;
$filter.conditions.InclLocalCopies = true;      

//Get the list:
$list = $item.getListUsingItems($filter, false, false);

//Load the list (this is the most important step, otherwise, the list will remain empty)
$list.load(true);

//Get the xml or the xml document
$list.getXml();
$list.getXmlDocument();
```

**Note**: You might have to add a listener (event handler) when you "load" the list to make sure you "wait" for the list to be loaded prior to use its contents.

Comment: Thanks Jamie - works well.  I might need the event handler, though, will test some more.

Comment: @robrtc you definitely need the load event handler, only time you don't need it is when this list is already in the cache.