# ItemType filter for Anguilla WhereUsed

Tags: cme, gui-extensions

I would like to filter the results from an Anguila WhereUsed query to return only Components based on a certain schema.  But, when I specify the ItemType or BasedOnSchema filters it returns no results.  Why do the filters not work?

The code is based on Jaime's solution here: [WhereUsed with Tridion Anguilla GUI Framework](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3801/whereused-with-tridion-anguilla-gui-framework)

**Update:  I have included my attemp to use a callback on the load method, but not sure if it is correct...**

```js
function ShowWhereUsed(c){
    // Begin Where Used
    //Get the item:
    $item = $models.getItem(c.getId()); 

    //Define a filter:
    $filter = new Tridion.ContentManager.ListFilter();
    $filter.columns = $const.ColumnFilter.DEFAULT;
    $filter.conditions.InclLocalCopies = true; 
    //$filter.conditions.ItemTypes = 16;    
    //$filter.conditions.BasedOnSchema = "tcm:174-277968-8";  // specifying a schema returns no results

    console.log('Before Load');
    //Get the list:
    $list = $item.getListUsingItems($filter, false, false);

    // register onload event for this item
    $evt.addEventHandler($list, "load", onItemLoaded);

    // call to load the item
    $list.load($list.isLoaded(true));
    //$list.load(true);

    console.log('After load');
}   

 // define onload delegate method
var onItemLoaded = function onItemLoaded() {
    console.log('onItemLoaded start');
    $evt.removeEventHandler(this, "load", onItemLoaded);

    // continue your code here
    var listXmlDoc = this.getXmlDocument();
    console.log(listXmlDoc);    
    ShowWhereUsedDisplayLinks(listXmlDoc);

    console.log('OnItemLoaded end');
};
```

With the below code (workaround, prefer to use above) I can get only Components, but then I also need to test for the Schema:

```js
var tridionItem = $models.getItem(compUri);
console.log(tridionItem);
var itemType = tridionItem.getInfo().ItemType;

if (itemType == $const.ItemType.COMPONENT)
{
    // Test for Schema here and show
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your list is loaded and not using a cached version which might not have your filter? I would recommend using the load event handler to make sure your list is fully loaded, see [my example in this answer](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2695/how-do-i-check-if-a-component-is-the-parent-or-a-copy-of-the-parent-using-the-tr/2700/#2700).

Comment: Hi Robert, will take a look, just a comment, I use "global" variables because I do my tests in the browser, but you should define them as local, for example $list, $item and $filter I would define as local, i.e., without the $ sign and with the "var" modifier before. Will try to check the Filtering capabilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just modified your function a little bit as follows:

```java
function ShowWhereUsed(itemUri, itemTypes, basedOnSchemas){
// Begin Where Used
//Get the item:
var item = $models.getItem(itemUri); 

//Define a filter:
var filter = new Tridion.ContentManager.ListFilter();
filter.columns = $const.ColumnFilter.DEFAULT;

//These are all the available conditions
//      ItemTypes: undefined,           // array of strings
    //      SubType: undefined,             // number
    //      LockFilter: undefined,          // Tridion.Constants.LockType
    //      LockResult: undefined,          // Tridion.Constants.LockType
    //      LockUser: undefined,            // user uri string
    //      Recursive: undefined,           // boolean
    //      SchemaPurpose: undefined,       // array of Tridion.Constants.SchemaPurpose
    //      ShowNewItems: undefined,        // boolean
    //      BasedOnSchema: undefined,       // array of uri strings 
    //      HideActiveDirectory: undefined, // boolean
    //      NoPredefined: undefined,        // boolean
    //      RelatedTo: undefined,           // array of uri's
    //      OnlyLatestVersions,             // boolean
    //      InPublication,                  // uri string
    //      InclLocalCopies,                // boolean
    //      InclParentItem,                 // boolean
    //      InclExternalLinks,              // boolean
    //      Enumeration,                    // string
    //      InfoType,                       // number, Model.getListPublishTransactionStates()
    //      StartDate,                      // Date
    //      EndDate,                        // Date
    //      User,                           // user uri string
    //      Publication,                    // publication uri string
    //      PublicationTarget,              // publication target uri string
    //      Priority,                       // number, Model.getListPublishPriorities()
    //      Abstract,                       // boolean, for Keywords
    //      Descendant,                     // boolean, for ListClassifiedItems
    //      ResultLimit                     // number, for ListClassifiedItems
    //      BasedOnItem: undefined,         // array of uri strings
    //      IncludeActiveProcesses          // boolean, for ListClassifiedItems
    //      DSGroupName                     // string, for ListDirectoryServiceTestUsers
    //      DSGroupSearchDN                 // string, for ListDirectoryServiceTestUsers
    //      DSGroupSearchType               // string, for ListDirectoryServiceTestUsers
    //      NSUserType                      // number, for ListNonSystemUsers
    //      NSUserName                      // string, for ListNonSystemUsers
    //      NSDomainName                    // string, for ListNonSystemUsers
    //      ItemIds                         // array, for SystemWideList

    //      ActivityState                   // number, for GetListActivityInstances
    //      IncludeAdditionalDateColumns    // boolean, for GetListActivityInstances
    //      IncludeWorkItems                // boolean, for GetListActivityInstances
    //      ForAllUsers                     // boolean, for GetListActivityInstances
    //      InclOnlyWorkflowBundles         // boolean, for GetListContainingBundles

    //      BluePrintItemId                 // string, for List which can contain Publications

filter.conditions.InclLocalCopies = true; 
filter.conditions.ItemTypes = itemTypes; //["16"] array of types   
filter.conditions.BasedOnSchema = basedOnSchemas; //["tcm:25-2816-8"] array of uris  
filter.conditions.OnlyLatestVersions = true;
//This is optional, depending on whether you wanna filter by the "owning" publication
filter.conditions.InPublication = item.getPublicationId();

var list = item.getListUsingItems(filter, false, false);


//Handler on load
var onItemLoaded = function onItemLoaded() {    
    $evt.removeEventHandler(list, "load", onItemLoaded);
    // continue your code here
    var listXmlDoc = list.getXmlDocument();
    var xml = list.getXml();
    console.debug(xml);
    console.debug(listXmlDoc);    
    //ShowWhereUsedDisplayLinks(listXmlDoc);

};

// call to load the item
if(!list.isLoaded()){
    // register onload event for this item
    $evt.addEventHandler(list, "load", onItemLoaded);
    list.load(list.isLoaded(true));
}else{
    onItemLoaded();
}    
}
```

Then you can call it with something like this:

```
ShowWhereUsed("tcm:1-234", ["16"], ["tcm:1-235-8"]);
```

**Note**: the filter by Schema uri doesn't seem to work very well, but the item type does indeed work.

Let me know what you think.

Comment: I agree the SchemaFilter doesn't seem to work, but the rest works great!  Thanks for the extra conditions such as OnlyLatestVersion and InPublication.

Answer (score 3):

I think your main problem now is in the definition of your filter. You try to set the conditions as properties, but they are mostly arrays I believe. See for instance the following examples which I got from the CME js files:

```js
var templateFilter = new Tridion.ContentManager.ListFilter(
{ 
    conditions: 
    { 
        ItemTypes: [ itemType ] 
    } 
});
```

or you could also set them like this:

```js
var filter = new Tridion.ContentManager.ListFilter();
filter.conditions.ItemTypes = [
    $const.ItemType.FOLDER,
    $const.ItemType.VIRTUAL_FOLDER
];
```

The Based On Schema seems to be set like this:

```js
filter.conditions.BasedOnSchema = options.basedOnSchema;
```

Where `options.basedOnSchema` holds the full TCM URI of a Schema it appears.

For more examples do a find in files in your `..\Tridion\web\WebUI\Editors\CME` folder and see where `Tridion.ContentManager.ListFilter` is used for example.