# How to get child publications in the Tridion JS Framework (Anguilla)?

Tags: where-used

I need to get child publications of a publication. I am using the following approach: get "where used" for the publication. Until now my code looks like this:

```
var id = publicationParent5TcmId;
var filter = new Tridion.ContentManager.ListFilter({columns: const.ColumnFilter.DEFAULT |$const.ColumnFilter.ALLOWED_ACTIONS |  $const.ColumnFilter.VERSIONS,    conditions:{InclLocalCopies: true}});

    var brothersPublications;
    var onSuccess = function () {
        if (brothersPublications) {
            $log.debug("WhereUsed.GetListUsingItems success: found " + brothersPublications.length + " brothers publications");
        }
        else {
            $log.debug("WhereUsed.GetListUsingItems success");
        }
    };

    var onFailed = function () {
        $log.debug("WhereUsed.GetListUsingItems failed");
    };

    brothersPublications = tridion.Web.UI.ContentManager.WhereUsed.GetListUsingItems(id, filter.conditions, filter.columns, onSuccess, onFailed);
```

It enters in onSuccess function, but brothersPublications is undefined.

Comment: Found a possible solution here: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3801/whereused-with-tridion-anguilla-gui-framework. Will check it.

Comment: Yeap, this is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to get your publication and then the child publications this way:

```
var parent_pub = $models.getItem("tcm:0-2-1");
var list = parent_pub.getListChildPublications();
```

Then iterate the resulting list to do something to every publication objects.